# add SSL to dropwizard with jetty

Tags: ssl, https, dropwizard

i have spend a lifetime while traying to configurate SSL for Dropwizard

what i do is to  start the dropwizard application with java -jar  command in my console

**NOT : i'am working right now on windows , but i'am planning to deploy the solution on linux after .**

when i start my application , all works fine :

```
INFO  [2018-10-16 16:23:26,739] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@24dc150c{/,null,AVAILABLE}
INFO  [2018-10-16 16:23:26,759] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started application@20231384{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFO  [2018-10-16 16:23:26,762] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started admin@3ba97962{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
INFO  [2018-10-16 16:23:26,762] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @3071ms
```

when i hit on my browser/or my android client a normal request the server show me this :

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [16/oct./2018:16:30:25 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 43 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" 69
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [16/oct./2018:16:30:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 43 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" 69
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [16/oct./2018:16:30:30 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 242 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" 8
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [16/oct./2018:16:30:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 553 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" 4
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [16/oct./2018:16:30:31 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 243 "http://localhost:8081/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" 1
```

but i have an other client who is configurate to work with SSL ( and it's the mean client, the others is just for the test )

when i hit the same request with HTTPS , that what happen :

```
WARN  [2018-10-16 16:32:29,216] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@12404fb3[p=1,l=517,c=8192,r=516]={\x16<<<\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFc\x03\x036\xD2T\xFd5\xF9\xCd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
```

googing this error i get tat is an problem with my server , he is not prepared to communicat with SSL

so how i can work with SSL or configurate SSL on jetty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix this by adding the the https params under server area on the yml config file

but i got some errors on  ssl handshake so i fixed by creating the keystore .